# What Scala implicit conversion on a Seq is happening here?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm reading Debasish Ghosh's new book, "Functional and Reactive Domain Modeling" and I'm really enjoying it.

One thing in Chapter 5 that has me puzzled is how the line below:

```
Reporting.report(accts).foreach(println _)
```

can take a Seq[Account] and convert it to a Seq[Show].  I know implicits are at play but what steps are the compiler taking to allow this to compile?  Is this just a specific instance of a more general implicit rule?  It *seems* like the compiler is mixing the Show trait into the Account objects.  Thanks!

Adapted from page 164:

```
import scala.util.Try

trait Show[T] {
  def shows(t: T): Try[String]
}

trait ShowProtocol {
  implicit val showAccount: Show[Account]
  implicit val showCustomer: Show[Customer]
}

trait DomainShowProtocol extends ShowProtocol {
  override implicit val showAccount: Show[Account] = (t: Account) => Try("Account")
  override implicit val showCustomer: Show[Customer] = (t: Customer) => Try("Customer")
}

case class Account()
case class Customer()

object Reporting {
  def report[T: Show](as: Seq[T]): Seq[Try[String]] = as.map(implicitly[Show[T]].shows _)
}

object DomainShowProtocol extends DomainShowProtocol

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import DomainShowProtocol._

    val accts: Seq[Account] = Seq(
      Account(),
      Account(),
      Account()
    )

    Reporting.report(accts).foreach(println _)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syntactic sugar**

```
def report[T: Show](seq: Seq[T])
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def report(seq: Seq[T])(implicit evidence: Show[T])
```

roughly you can assume

```
[T: Show]
```

does the job of

```
(implicit evidence: Show[T])

implicitly[Show[T]]
```

is nothing but the reference of the implicit Show[T]

trait `DomainShowProtocol` has a implicit evidence `Show[Account]`

```
object DomainShowProtocol extends DomainShowProtocol
```

Now using the object `DomainShowProtocol` implicit is imported into scope.

`report` method is able to convert `Seq[Account]` to `Seq[Try[String]]` because of the `implicit` evidence from object `DomainShowProtocol` which in turn is coming from trait `DomainShowProtocol`

```
def report[T: Show](as: Seq[T]): Seq[Try[String]] = as.map(implicitly[Show[T]].shows _)
```

above function is the syntactic sugar for

```
def report(as: Seq[T])(implicit evidence: Show[T]): Seq[Try[String]] = as.map(evidence.shows _)
```

Here `T` is `Account` and implicit evidence `Show[Account]` is comming from the object `DomainShowProtocol`. Thats how this conversion is possible.

Comment: thanks for your edits.  They really helped me get the syntactic sugaring that's going on and the notes you made on evidence was completely new to me so thanks for the "Aha!" moments!

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty straight-forward use of the typeclass pattern.  All of the "magic" happens in the `report` function.

First notice the type parameter:

```
def report[T: Show]
```

This means that whatever type `T` is, there must be an implicit `Show[T]` in scope at the call-site.  In `Main`, the function is called where `T` is `Account`, and thus requires an implicit `Show[Account]` to be in scope at that line.  Since `Main` mixes in `DomainShowProtocol`, the implicit val `showAccount` is in scope, so that requirement is satisfied.

Now in the body of `report`, we see the use of `implicitly[Show[T]]`.  This simply returns a reference to that very `Show[T]` that was required to be in scope, so in this case it is equal to `showAccount`.

Lastly, the `show` method is called on the implicitly returned value, passing in the current element of the `Seq` as a parameter.  This converts each `Account` into a `Try[String]` and thus the `Seq` as a whole.

If we remove all the implicit magic, the method and its invocation look like :

```
//in Reporting
def report[T](as: Seq[T])(show: Show[T]): Seq[Try[String]] = {
  as.map{t => show.shows(t)}
}

//in Main
Reporting.report(accts)(accountsShow).foreach(println _)
```